# Save text to a text file already created

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am currently trying to do this question for tafe but am having trouble getting it to add text to the file after the first time.

"Create an application that at start up asks the user to choose an output file using a Save File Dialog Window. The application to have a “Write to File” button that when clicked will take a name and age that the user has entered into two text boxes and write them directly to the file. The user can repeat the button click action as often as they wish."

This is my current code for it:

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveFileDialog1.Title = ("Choose Save Location");
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
}

private void btnSendToFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strName = txtName.Text;
    string strAge = txtAge.Text;
    string strTitles = ("Name \t\t Age");
    string strCombined = strTitles + "\n" + (strName + "\t\t" + strAge);
    System.IO.StreamWriter OutFile;

    MessageBox.Show("The Name and Age of the Person Entered Will be Written to a File");

    OutFile = System.IO.File.CreateText(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
    OutFile.WriteLine(strCombined);

    OutFile.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("The Details Have Been Written to File" + saveFileDialog1.FileName);

    StreamWriter AddFile = File.AppendText(saveFileDialog1.FileName);

    AddFile.Write(strCombined);
}
```

I'm not sure if I should be doing a loop or not and this is the form itself, https://gyazo.com/e2c4170d46295d6f92a35026e1f2304b

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you're doing you absolutely don't need to work with streams or anything that low level (you don't need to call the create methods on files and use a stream returned by it). You can directly use the methods that write or append to the file and handle all of this for you.

For example using AppendAllText will do everything for you (managing the streams, flushing and closing them, appending at the end, creating the file if it doesn't exist etc etc).

so you can replace all of this code :

```
    System.IO.StreamWriter OutFile;
    MessageBox.Show("The Name and Age of the Person Entered Will be Written to a File");
    OutFile = System.IO.File.CreateText(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
    OutFile.WriteLine(strCombined);
    OutFile.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("The Details Have Been Written to File" + saveFileDialog1.FileName);
```

with

```
    File.AppendAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, strCombined);
```

I have no idea what you're doing in the code that follows it (calling appendtext, i assume you're thinking you need to append after creating?) in any case you don't need it. So if you just want to append all the text of "strcombined" at the end of the file each time you click the whole function should look like :

```
private void btnSendToFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strName = txtName.Text;
    string strAge = txtAge.Text;
    string strTitles = ("Name \t\t Age");
    string strCombined = strTitles + "\n" + (strName + "\t\t" + strAge);

    MessageBox.Show("The Name and Age of the Person Entered Will be Written to a File");
    File.AppendAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, strCombined);
    MessageBox.Show("The Details Have Been Written to File" + saveFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

Also as a side comment i would rewrite all of it as such for readability, these are suggestions and not hard rules:

1) Removed hungarian notation (Don't add a prefix to your variable to indicate it's type, it's generally frowned upon)

2) Removed a lot of the temporary variables that aren't really needed (used once in the same local function)

This makes for a much smaller and very readable function:

```
private void btnSendToFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The Name and Age of the Person Entered Will be Written to a File");
    File.AppendAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName,"Name \t\t Age"+ "\n" + txtName.Text + "\t\t" + txtAge.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("The Details Have Been Written to File" + saveFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```